# jQuery Asynchronous Image Loader Woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jail

Using jQuery JAIL (jQuery Asynchronous Image Loader) in my site, I've followed all the instructions correctly but for some reason, the images always load first before the plugin takes place... I have it set up so that the images should fadeIn after a 1000ms delay but the images load completely, quickly black out and then fade in. any ideas anyone? lazyload has apparently become obsolete so I need to make this work. Thanks

Comment: have you tried setting their display to none in your css and showing via js after your plugin has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have used the URL for the image in the src attribute, you need to use a small place holder image for the src attribute and the data-href attribute for the real image URL.